# Autoload do composer não encontra classe

Tags: php, composer

Registrei o `autoload` no `composer.json`

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Racioly\\MeuPackage\\": "src/"
    }
}
```

Criei uma pasta chamada `test` na raiz do projeto, e criei também um arquivo `teste.php`, este arquivo contém o seguinte código:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

use Racioly\MeuPackage\Complex;

var_dump(new Complex(2110));
```

Dentro de `src` eu tenho a classe `Complex`:

```
namespace Complex;

class Complex {
...
}
```

Porém quando rodo o arquivo através do terminal `php teste.php` recebo o erro:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Racioly\MeuPackage\Complex' not found in ... teste.php:7

que é exatamente onde testo a instância de `Complex` no `var_dump()`

Comment: Sua classe `complex` esta importante o namespace `Complex`, porém, no composer você esta definindo que a pasta `src` tem a origem do namespace `Racioly\MeuPackage\ `. Na classe `Complex` você precisa importante ela para este namespace. Leia mais sobre https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-4-autoloader.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você atualizou seu autoload.php?

Tente rodar o seguinte comando dentro da sua pasta raiz (composer.json)

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Fiz alguns testes aqui e rodou normalmente, segue meu código de exemplo.

composer.json

```
{
    "name": "teste/teste",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Jean Souza",
            "email": "jeancsouzak@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "require": {},
    "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Racioly\\MeuPackage\\": "src/"
    }
}
}
```

Complex.php (classe está dentro do diretorio src)

```
<?php
namespace Racioly\MeuPackage;

class Complex {

    public function __construct($x)
    {
      echo $x;
    }

}
```

index.php (na raiz do projeto)

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Racioly\MeuPackage\Complex;

var_dump(new Complex(213123));
```

Resultado:

```
213123object(Racioly\MeuPackage\Complex)#2 (0) { }
```

Comment: Eu havia colocado o namespace errado. obrigado.